# OPTIONS method not allowed when asking for OAuth2 token

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth-2.0, authorization, restify

I've got a simple **node.js** backend build on **Restify** with **OAuth2** authorization implemented (restify-oauth2 plugin).

I've got a problem requesting a token. When I call POST method with my REST client, everything works correctly and I get `access_token` and `token_type`.

The problem occurs when I try to do the same thing in my frontend aplication made in **Angular** using **Restangular**. It calls **OPTIONS** method before sending actual **POST**, and the server responds with an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/token?grant_type=client_credentials.
Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Here are my CORS settings on backend:

```
server.pre(
function crossOrigin(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    return next();
  }
);
server.use(restify.fullResponse());
```

And this is REST call used in the frontend:

```
Restangular.one('token').post(
  null, 
  null, 
  {grant_type: "client_credentials"}, 
  {Authorization: "Basic bXlsb2dpbjpteXBhc3M="}
)
```

Can somebody help me figure out how to get it to work?

Comment: You haven't setup your server to respond to OPTIONS requests, hence the "Method not allowed" statuscode. You set it up in the same way you respond to GET requests. `server.options('*',function (req,res,next){...});`

Comment: Unfortunately /token endpoint is generated automatically by OAuth2 plugin. I have no idea how to set it's response to OPTIONS requests. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25532150/400654

Comment: @KevinB This accually helped. Thanks a lot