# AWS Cors Issue - Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-s3

I am currently experiencing an issue when requesting images stored on AWS S3 (simple storage) with the CORS header. I have set up the CORS configuaration on the AWS console - and the setup is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

However, the response I get when requesting these images that I've stored are a little all over the place and quite intermittent. Sometimes the image is returned with the headers requred and sometimes it is not. I am really not sure why this happens. It also seems that the effect worsens when I try to make more than one request for an image with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set as * on a page (e.g. If I need 10 images to be retrieved all with cross origin headers).

These are the headers that I need:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3000
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. I have made sure that each image tag has the crossOrigin="anonymous" attribute added to it too, but again, no luck.

The reason for me needing these images to work cross origin is because I have installed an angular plugin which allows the user to crop images and store the cropped versions of the images as base64 strings. However, I get the following error when trying to retrive them.

[image]

These are the headers for an image that is returned correctly:

```
Request URL:https://trajansmarket.s3.amazonaws.com/be5bbda0-b04a-11e5-81d3-dd7ff3efeebc.jpg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:54.231.252.131:443

Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3000
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000
Date:Tue, 12 Jan 2016 21:13:03 GMT
ETag:"77bdbe9b517acc8cba86024c592bce3f"
Last-Modified:Fri, 01 Jan 2016 05:46:21 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Vary:Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2:F3OQpOHsAqySk9LNwwoJXVATVIByr4Gtvz953ZoL7DdB/dtE9nYwo99R59Rj6RzZc3dcHyk6wWY=
x-amz-request-id:CD220FF1F6EE6CA9

Request Headers
view source
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:trajansmarket.s3.amazonaws.com
If-None-Match:"77bdbe9b517acc8cba86024c592bce3f"
Origin:http://91.121.220.161:3000
Referer:http://91.121.220.161:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
```

And here's one without the headers:

```
Request URL:https://trajansmarket.s3.amazonaws.com/c0671e00-b04a-11e5-81d3-
dd7ff3efeebc.jpg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
Remote Address:54.231.252.135:443

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000
Content-Length:142102
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Tue, 12 Jan 2016 00:35:36 GMT
ETag:"beb93f56e3a2a65b983addd8af35c26c"
Last-Modified:Fri, 01 Jan 2016 05:46:25 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2:5XvaOd8bxMr5zwK317DfDMbk2+kzu3Zd7rsf2xl0hxwI40Oc4KDnQpgzD3sgtCRm9SXGqa93Mh0=
x-amz-request-id:FD3EB1978C38013B

Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Origin:http://91.121.220.161:3000
Referer:http://91.121.220.161:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:498F45FE-5D49-4AE0-AF58-F81B9AFD48AF
```

I'm just wondering if anyone would have any idea of why this would be happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your browsers developer tools network tab, can you confirm that you are receiving the required cors headers

Comment: Hi, it's intermittent. Sometimes I receive the images with the headers and then sometimes after a refresh I don't. It's almost like the CORS rule isn't worked correctly with AWS for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: so, you don't always receive the CORS headers - seems to be an issue with AWS

Comment: I thought as much. Looks like I'm going to have to have a chat with their support team to try and resolve it which means I may have to upgrade plans :(

Comment: could a cached response negate the need for a preflight request, or might a cached response lose some headers?

Comment: I also thought that it may be to do with the cached response, but as I sometimes get the headers and sometimes don't, I didn't think it would be down to the caching. What do you think?

Comment: Try sending the next request with Cache-Control: no-cache header

Comment: @dandavis It was losing some of the headers in the cache for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a very frustrating and I am still yet to work out the reason for AWS S3 intermittently returned the headers that I need for CORS.

I have since thought of a workaround which is to 'download' and store the images that I need from amazon in a local folder - allow the user to 'crop' the image and store it before then deleting these images from the local folder.

To stream the image files to a local folder I used the fs.createWriteStream method on the .getObject method from s3. An example of this can be found at: [enter link description here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html)

This has taken away the need for me to actually request the images with the CORS headers as when they are stored locally, the headers are no longer required. I can then save the base64 that is generated by my cropper directive and store this on amazon S3 easily.

If the user navigates away before cropping the local images I delete them from the local folder so it doesn't get clogged up.

I hope this is of some help to those who are also having issues with the CORS headers - even though it's just a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Well I've seen this problem in a number of different forms: 
one is where you are serving a page in S3 that access a nodejs backend in either an EC2 or in Elastic Beanstalk.

In one case it was the browser I was using IE10 that threw errors because the browser required Preflight options to be set.

In the other cases I was using Restify in Elastic Beanstalk and Angular in S3. I added the Restify-cors middleware package to the request:

```
var corsMiddleWare = require('restify-cors-middleware'); //npm install this package
var cors = corsMiddleWare ({
    allowHeaders:['Authorization', 'API-Token', 'API-Token-Expiry']
 });
server.pre(cors.preflight);
server.use(cors.actual);
//rest of server definition
```

This seemed to work.
In the case of express there is the node package express-cors:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

In either case the key is that all requests must have the headers set properly, hence we add them to middleware. (app/server.use)
[How can I support cors when using restify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338683/how-can-i-support-cors-when-using-restify)

Are you using vanilla node? In that case you need to add the headers on every request you make to s3.

Answer (score 0):

This was definitely an issue with it being a cached response for me. It seems to lose some of the headers in cache. I was able to get it to work 100% of the time by appending a random time parameter to the image name, as in the example below.

```
img = new Image();
img.src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/img.png?t=" + (new Date().getTime() / 1000);    
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
```